# Wordpress database nonsense error

Tags: site-url

I'm very confused. What i did was change my hostfiles so i can access my website on an alternative website and checked it in case i had hardcoded values (i did and they were corrected). I had to use the defines below to get the check to work

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

Anyways, after i checked everything i did some select queries in my db (confirmed by looking at history). When i undid the define and change my host files back so my original url isnt poiting to home i tried visiting my wp site and i got "Error establishing a database connection". copied pasted the login data into mysql -u name -p (pass) and i was able to log in... i dont know why wp cant login. I tried reseting my server, mysql server and php-fastcgi. All didnt fix it :(. How do i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, i actually accidentally didnt put back the url in nginx config file so i only had the new url. I wonder why i got a DB error instead of my generic "Nothing to see here" page